# Configuring Windows 2003 As A Router

Tags: routing, static-routes, windows-server-2003

I am trying to configure a Windows 2003 server to act as a router, so that the two subnetworks that I'm dealing with can communicate with one another without NAT.  I am mostly sure that I have configured Windows 2003 incorrectly, and I'm finding it very difficult to drill down through Google results to something helpful.

I have a 192.168.1.0/24 network that is my "production" network (in the sense that I'm in trouble if I screw it up) and a 10.0.0.0/8 network that is my test network.  The 192.168.1.0 network is ruled by a gateway whose routing table looks like this (my address redacted):

[192.168.1.0 gateway http://stronglyemergent.com/wp-content/uploads/routingtable2.png](http://stronglyemergent.com/wp-content/uploads/routingtable2.png)

The Windows 2003 server, "prime," is multihomed.  Its network adapters are at 192.168.1.122, (as seen above), 10.0.0.1, and 10.0.0.2.  I added the Routing and Remote Access role to it, and enabled LAN routing.  I do not have it using RIP or other routing protocols.  Its current routing table is shown below.

[windows 2003 server http://stronglyemergent.com/wp-content/uploads/routingtable.gif](http://stronglyemergent.com/wp-content/uploads/routingtable.gif)

To me, it looks like all of the right routes are there for traffic to pass between the 192.168.1.0 network and the 10.0.0.0 network.  However, traffic does not pass.  The 10.0.0.11 and .12 clients cannot be contacted from the 192.168.1.0 network.  When I use traceroute to try to get to them, the trace gets to the Windows 2003 server's 192.168.1.122 address, then produces nothing but "* * *" timeouts.  When I try to traceroute to 192.168.1.1 from a 10.0.0.0-network client, I get "destination host unreachable."  However, I know that the routing is working at least a little, because from the 192.168.1.0 network, I can connect to the Windows server just fine by referring to it as 10.0.0.1.

What static routes would allow me to contact 10.0.0.11 and .12 from the 192.168.1.0 network?

Is it possible to tell the Windows server "since you are a DHCP/DNS server, you already know routes to get to machines that are getting IP addresses from you, please add those to your routing table" ?

Will using RIP or OSPF on the Windows server actually be helpful in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you enabled routing on windows 2003? check [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323339).

RIP / OSPF are helpful if you have larger network of devices that can handle those protocols.

Comment: +1 - routing may simply not be enabled yet ;)

Comment: I've been sticking with the GUI tools for now, so I haven't made that registry edit.  Trying that now.

Comment: Took a while to kick in, but that seems to have worked.  Gosh, editing the Registry directly is so much more convenient than a GUI tool or a shell command.